# How to specify what will be the export build js and css filenames in svelte

Tags: svelte, vite

I am using vite for svelte, I have attached vite.config.js below, I tried looking for references on the web but couldn't find any

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 4000
  },
  preview: {
    port: 4000
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        customElement: true,
      }
    }),
  ]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are options for that under [`build > rollupOptions`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#big-list-of-options), e.g.

```js
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte(),
    ],
});
```

Note that the generated hashes exist for caching purposes, if those are removed, you will have to take care of cache invalidation manually. For something like a component library that would not be an issue, of course.

There is an option [`build.manifest`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-manifest), that can be used to output mappings from original source to compiled output which could be used to determine the output name, rather than changing the above rollup options. E.g. if a server has to generate `<script src="...">` tags, this can be used.